# Printing from txt file leaves a line in between

Tags: python

I'm using this code:

```py
konto_fail = open("konto.txt")
for line in konto_fail:
    if float(line) > 0:
        print (line)
```

If I run the program it prints out the necessary lines, but there is a empty line in between them that I don't want. How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the last char of `line` is `\n` aka a newline.

To prevent that from happening, do a

```
print(line, end='')
```

The default `end` is `\n` so by default, you add two new lines (one in the string, and one at the end of the print).

---

That means that the solution I provided above is equivalent to

```
print(line[:-1])
```

You can also remove all newlines by doing

```
print(line.replace('\n', ''))
```

Remove all trailing whitespaces (including newlines)

```
print(line.strip())
```

Remove all trailing whitespaces (including newlines) at the end

```
print(line.rstrip())
```

Remove all trailing whitespaces (including newlines) at the beginning

```
print(line.lstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Python syntax for printing is different than other languages. Printing the next output in the next line is default. So, to change it, put an `end=''`(if not specified, `end` is `\n`) as the last attribute of the function `print()`

```
konto_fail = open("konto.txt")
for line in konto_fail:
    if float(line) > 0:
        print (line, end = '')
```